# R: Group the closest points

Tags: r, spatial-analyst

I am looking for a solution where I could group points that are nearest to each other in the given area. Having points lon/lat I would like to know how many groups with points closest to each other or by determining the number of points to find out how many points groups are located in the area. Did anyone perform such an analysis and could share the solution?

Comment: How about using something like kmeans clustering to cluster points together? This example can get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672399/spatial-clustering-in-r-simple-example